# Deep copy 2 dimensional Array of Objects

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

In my project I manipulate a multidimensional array which consists of Objects. After the manipulation I want to "reset" the array. I tested dozens of "deep copy" codes from here and all over the web but no one seems to work with multidimensional Arrays. I'm on Java 7. Can you provide a hint?

> By Reset I mean to the initial state before manipulation. So I want to create a backup of my array and restore it later.

Comment: your question cannot be answered unless you define "reset"

Comment: Rest to inital state before manipulation. So I want to create a backup of my array and restore it later

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have merged your comment into your question.  Please edit your question next time when you are enhancing it.  Sometimes it is preferable to make it clear, where you have edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should accomplish a deep copy of the array in question.

```
private static class CloneableObject
        implements
            Cloneable {

    @Override
    public CloneableObject clone() {
        return new CloneableObject();
    }
}


CloneableObject[][] original;


void someMethod() {
    CloneableObject[][] copy = Arrays.copyOf(this.original, this.original.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {
        copy[i] = Arrays.copyOf(copy[i], copy[i].length);
        for (int j = 0; j < copy[i].length; j++) {
            copy[i][j] = copy[i][j].clone();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Manipulation of this.original is to be done here
     * None of the manipulations will be reflected in copy
     * 
     * Note that (this.original[n][m] == copy[n][m]) will evaluate to false,
     * where n and m are arbitrary indices of the array.
     */

    this.original = copy; // "reset"
}
```

If it is desired that the instances of `Object` not be copied, simply delete the inner loop.

Comment: What is ment by "Arrays" in the code? My IDE says that it is not defined and doesn't offer a package to be imported

Comment: Figured out by myself that java.util.Arrays is meant but now it says that an expression is expected at Arrays<Object>

Comment: Indeed it is meant to be java.util.Arrays. The places where it is written `<Object>`, it should not be. There are also some issues in the inner loop, I will revise and make an edit to the answer.

Comment: @laufi There, I have now revised the code. This should work.